# Why is my C program slower than its C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, c, performance

I've wanted to do a small benchmark test between C and C#, so I wrote the following programs:

C:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 500000)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

C#:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= 500000)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I compiled them and ran both at the same time.

To my surprise, the C# program has exited about 5 seconds earlier than the C program.

C is a language well-known for its high speed and great performance, so how could it be that in this case, the C# program outperformed the C program significantly in such a simple task? I thought that C# is much slower because it compiles in runtime, but it easily defeated the native executable that was compiled from C.

What is the reason for this, and does this also happen in other types of programs?

I ran these 2 programs on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, if that matters, and compiled the C# program in C# Express 2010, and the C program in VS2013 Express for Desktop.

**And please don't bash me for "such a common question"** - Yes, I've seen another answers, but they all dealt with complex things such as memory management and buffer size, and the programs in here are very simple and do not deal with those things.

I've also tried replacing `printf` for `puts`, but that was just as slow.

Comment: Your programs spend almost no time in the code you wrote, so it doesn't matter how it is compiled. They are spending all their time in the runtime library.

Comment: *'I thought that C# is much slower because it compiles in runtime'* - Not *necessarily* true. Yes, C# is JIT compiled - but the compiled executable code is cached, so if you run the same program twice, it won't need to re-JIT the code the second time round. In the end, the machine code instructions from your 2 programs (minus the console invocation / printf) will probably be extremely similar, so I wouldn't expect much of a performance difference.

Comment: printf has to parse the format spec at run time - using itoa would be more comparable to what C# is doing.  But I agree the console I/O will be the overwhelming bottleneck.

Comment: It is a common question :) symptomatic of the general state of programmers' understanding. It's an example of the [*streetlight effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect), where the only thing considered is the code one can see.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I now understand that this is far more complex than what it actually seems, and that each language (C and C#) prints strings to the screen slightly differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with the C language or its compiler, everything to do with its runtime support library.  The slow-down is caused by you using printf().

The C Runtime Library (CRT) is badly stuck in the mud, modeling a runtime environment that harks back to the 1970s.  Back when programmers used a teletype to talk to a computer, one that had a very primitive operating system that didn't support goodies like threading, talking in English.

That runtime environment is a very drastic mismatch with modern operating systems,considerable overhead is needed to emulate it.  The C language in general has pretty poor support for Unicode for example.  So every string you output has to be painstakingly converted to the native operating system's string format, utf-16 in Windows.  The .NET Framework uses System.String, a string type that's encoded in utf-16 as well.  Even down to the lowest level, Windows requires string to be zero-terminated, just like C strings need to be.  Every .NET string is automatically zero-terminated, even the ones you don't use for I/O.  So no conversion is required, the framework can directly call the operating system function that outputs the string.

That's not where it ends.  The notion of threading is completely alien to the CRT, it was never designed to consider the ramifications of multiple threads, say, modifying the locale or simultaneously writing text.  So the CRT is peppered with low-level locks to bring this to a good end.  Overhead that is very rarely actually useful, but must be taken because the 1970s runtime  model doesn't disallow nor account for it.

You can make your C program just as fast as your C# program, making it *noticeably* faster is a bit stretch, but you have to bypass the 1970s to do so.  Using wprintf() instead already ought to make a noticeable difference, you don't get parity until you call WriteConsoleW() or WriteFile().

Do note that this does not actually matter at all.  The text is scrolling across the screen far faster than a human can read it anyway.  So it is not a real problem that anybody would consider fixing.

Comment: ... and writing to the console is mainly a matter of doing a lot of painting and scrolling.

Comment: Well, it seems to be much more complicated than what I originally thought. It seems that even the most basic procedures are complex in what they're exactly doing, and I've absolutely never thought of this in the context of string conversions (I thought `printf` and `Console.Write` will eventually output the same assembly code - either in JIT or in AOT - and I was wrong). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

Benchmarking how fast a programming language can write to the console is worthless. That's the bottleneck in both of these cases, and it's screwing up your results. The execution time of one of the programs, either the C or C# version, would vary wildly from one run to the next. So any comparisons between the two languages are meaningless.

If you *really* want to test the performance difference, one way to do it would be to write a complicated mathematical algorithm and benchmark that. Don't write the result to the console, though—you now know that would defeat the purpose! Also, time it using a high-resolution timer. In C#, you'd use the [`Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx); in C (at least on Windows), you'd call the [`QueryPerformanceCounter` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx). Timing with [a *real* stopwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgo9H.jpg) is just too error-prone. Or at least it is for me. Either way, make sure you query these values *outside* of the code you're testing.

Comment: definitely +1 for pointing out that benchmarking `printf` is pointless and has nothing to with "language performance" in any sense.

Comment: Thank you very much. After all you're right - benchmarking on the console is actually useless because it's just not intended for such performance tests. This bottleneck, according to what you say, won't happen in real performance tests done with the correct tools and at the correct method. Thanks again for your answer!